# How to search for specific text in csv within a Pandas, python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hello I want to find the account text @ in the title column, and save it in the new csv. Pandas can do it, I tried to make it but it didn't work.
This is my csv http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c1ed9790f481a8d452049be439f4e3d8/Newnormal.csv

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

  
data = pd.read_csv("Newnormal.csv")
data.dropna(inplace = True) 

  

sub ='@'
  
data["Indexes"]= data["title"].str.find(sub)
print(data)
```

I want results like this

> From, to, title Xavier5501,KudiiThaufeeq,RT @KudiiThaufeeq: Royal
> Rape, Royal Harassment, Royal Cocktail Party, Royal Pedo, Royal
> Bidding, Royal Maalee Bayaan, Royal Slavery..et

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. reduce records to only those that have an "@" in title
2. define new column which is text between "@" and ":"
3. you are left with some records where this leave NaN in to column.  I've just filtered these out

```
df = pd.read_csv("Newnormal.csv")
df = df[df["title"].str.contains("@")==True]
df["to"] = df["title"].str.extract(r".*([@][A-Z,a-z,0-9,_]+[:])")
df = df[["from","to","title"]]
df[~df["to"].isna()].to_csv("ToNewNormal.csv", index=False)
df[~df["to"].isna()]
```

**output**

```
    from    to  title
1   Xavier5501  @KudiiThaufeeq: RT @KudiiThaufeeq: Royal Rape, Royal Harassmen...
2   Suzane24979006  @USAID_NISHTHA: RT @USAID_NISHTHA: Don't step outside your hou...
3   sandeep_sprabhu @USAID_NISHTHA: RT @USAID_NISHTHA: Don't step outside your hou...
4   oliLince    @Timothy_Hughes:    RT @Timothy_Hughes: How to Get a Salesforce Th...
7   rismadwip   @danielepermana:    RT @danielepermana: Pak kasus covid per hari s...
... ... ... ...
992 Reptoid_Hunter  @sapiofoxy: RT @sapiofoxy: I literally can't believe we ha...
994 KPCResearch @sapiofoxy: RT @sapiofoxy: I literally can't believe we ha...
995 GreySparkUK @VoxSmartGlobal:    RT @VoxSmartGlobal: The #newnormal will see mo...
997 Gabboa10    @HuShameem: RT @HuShameem: One of @PGO_MV admin staff test...
999 wanjirunjendu   @ntvkenya:  RT @ntvkenya: AAK's Mugure Njendu shares insig...
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping, i mean without changes if there is no @ fill n / a, do not delete. the results of the script that you provide remove the missing ones @.

Comment: Can you express in better terms?  The reg expr I've provided matches most cases,  however you know your data intimately.  Can you describe in structured form what you need?